# maven-ear-plugin, Cannot find 'version' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.ear.EjbModule

Tags: java, maven, ear

Desperatley trying to create a EAR bundle with some modules, using the maven EAR plugin version 2.10.1 with Maven 3. There is a problem with the generate-application-xml goal, I´m getting the error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10.1:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project wineapp-ear: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10.1:generate-application-xml for parameter version: Cannot find 'version' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.ear.EjbModule -> [Help 1]

here is the pom.xml snippet:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <artifactId>wineapp-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>wineapp-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>wineapp-ear</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
        <artifactId>wineapp-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
        <artifactId>wineapp-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
        <artifactId>wineapp-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
        <artifactId>wineapp-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<version>6</version>-->
                <!--<applicationXml>/src/main/application/META-INF/</applicationXml>-->
                <modules>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wineapp-ejb</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <bundleFileName>ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wineapp-web</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <bundleFileName>web.war</bundleFileName>
                    </webModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wineapp-common</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                        <bundleFileName>common.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wineapp-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                        <bundleFileName>jpa.jar</bundleFileName>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

what the hack is wrong here? or is it just a f.. typo in the xml? inside the configuration element, the automatic tag detection by IDE (how is the word for that..) also not working, but i compared it with examples nearly a thousand times. don´t know what else matters for error finding, there´s also a parent pom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An module did not have a version tag see [modules](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html). The version is already defined by the dependency blog and the module blog is just use for renaming the artifacts in the ear file (since you define a new bundleFileName). So try to remove all version tags in your modules like this:

```
           <modules>
                <ejbModule>
                    <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wineapp-ejb</artifactId>
                    <bundleFileName>ejb.jar</bundleFileName>
                </ejbModule>
                <webModule>
                    <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wineapp-web</artifactId>
                    <bundleFileName>web.war</bundleFileName>
                </webModule>
                <jarModule>
                    <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wineapp-common</artifactId>
                    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                    <bundleFileName>common.jar</bundleFileName>
                </jarModule>
                <jarModule>
                    <groupId>com.jueggs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wineapp-jpa</artifactId>
                    <bundleDir>lib</bundleDir>
                    <bundleFileName>jpa.jar</bundleFileName>
                </jarModule>
            </modules>
```

Or better remove the complete modules blog because I do not think its important for you to rename the dependencies in the ear and it is OK to use the Maven default names.

Comment: This answer helps me. Just remove the complete modules blog. I thought it is needed to specify on how to package the project.